# XML - XSLT Clear one field vale if both field values are same

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt, Can some one help me to this scenario. If both field values are same clear one filed value. below scenario First EMP EE_WORKMOBPH should not have any value in return.

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <emp>
        <EE_WORKMOBPH>123</EE_WORKMOBPH>
        <EE_MOBPH>123</EE_MOBPH>
    </emp>
    <emp>
        <EE_WORKPH>345</EE_WORKPH>
        <EE_WORKMOBPH>678</EE_WORKMOBPH>
    </emp>
</root>
```

`

Expected Result:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <emp>
        <EE_WORKMOBPH></EE_WORKMOBPH>
        <EE_MOBPH>123</EE_MOBPH>
    </emp>
    <emp>
        <EE_WORKPH>345</EE_WORKPH>
        <EE_WORKMOBPH>678</EE_WORKMOBPH>
    </emp>
</root>
```

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="root/emp/ee_workmobph/text()">
        <xsl:if test="ee_workbobph = ee_mobph">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XML is case-sensitive: `ee_workmobph` is NOT the same as `EE_WORKMOBPH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want do:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="EE_WORKMOBPH[.=../EE_MOBPH]/text()"/>        

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I really appreciate it. the above code is working only for the first employee but not the second employee. Would you please suggest me on this.

Comment: The second employee does not meet your criteria of "both field values are same". In addition, the field names are not the same. It is not possible to provide a complete answer when the rules are not completely clear.